# How to calculate the average of a value using while loop?

Tags: r

I have a list of values and I need to sum all of it and calculate the average value using while loop. I just can't figure out how to create a condition that will allow me to do so.

Anyone have an idea of how to calculate it using while?

Comment: Wh you need a `while` loop.  Wouldn't just `mean(yourvector)`

Comment: It's for a college assignment, so I necessarily  have to do it using a while loop.

Comment: Given all your 600 values within a `numeric` vector (`vector_of_values`), initialize `sum <- 0` and `i <- 1` and `n <- length(vector_of_values)`, then loop with `while(i <= n){sum <- sum + vector_of_values[i]; i <- i + 1}` and finally `avg_value <- sum / n`.  TBH, this question has almost certainly been answered elsewhere, and it is quite elementary, so I'd recommend you (1) read instructional resources on control structures (like `while`-loops, `for`-loops, etc.) and on R; and (2) if you're still stuck, search for an existing answer to this question in particular.

Comment: It should be noted that the algorithm for this calculation, using a `while`-loop, has been implemented in many languages.  Even if there is somehow no answer to this question in R, there will be an answer in a different language.  With R documentation as a reference, it should be trivial to translate that implementation into R syntax.

Comment: `done = FALSE; while(!done) { result = mean(x); done = TRUE }`

Comment: @GregorThomas I enjoy this cheeky answer, but let's not confuse Romano (a student who is learning R) about control structures. Romano's teacher wants the algorithm implemented in full.

Comment: Also, the cheeky answer could be condensed into `while(TRUE){result <- mean(x); break}`, which misses the point even _more_ efficiently!

Comment: I appreciate all answers and @Greg, you're an angel. I finally understood what I'm supposed to do and will follow your recommendations.

Comment: My pleasure!  As long as you use the [_serious_ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120204695), your teacher should be satisfied.